# Can't show SVN diff via the Phabricator's checkout files

Tags: svn, diff, phabricator

I have done diffusion settings in Phabricator. It's fine when I checkout from Phabricator via SVN.
When I want to compare the difference between revisions, it got no responding.
I also tried it via command line and found other command worked well except comparing between revisions.
Anyone knows how to fix it?
[Try to show changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WpK5.png)
[No responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUTcA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgrade TortoiseSVN to 1.8 and I can use diff now.
If you use smartsvn, ver8.6 works well.